# URL Rewriting Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to accomplish a rewrite in nginx, but it isn't working.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
www.website.com/backstage/somepage.php?language=Dutch
```

should become

```
www.website.com/nl/backstage/somepage.php
```

I have added this line to the nginx config (but it isn't doing anything):

```
rewrite ^/nl/backstage/(.*)\.html$ /./backstage/$1.php?language=Dutch last;
```

I hope someone can help :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

humm, I don't understand your rewrite directive, it doesn't make much sense. check the doc : http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule and in particular

```
rewrite regex replacement
```

So you have to find a regex that matches /backstage/somepage.php?language=Dutch
and replacement would be /nl/backstage/somepage.php . However, this one is tricky as you are trying to rewrite according to a parameter. So "rewrite" alone doesn't work, you have to use "if".

This should work:

```
if ($args ~ language=Dutch){
  rewrite ^/backstage/(.*).php$ /nl/backstage/$1.php permanent;
}
```